# Drawing gridlines in cartopy map

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am drawing the map above using cartopy and the foll. code:

```
gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True, alpha=0.35)
gl.xlabels_top = False
gl.ylabels_left = False
gl.xlocator = mticker.FixedLocator([-120, -60, 0, 60, 120])
gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
```

How do I restrict this to only draw gridlines for -23.5 N, 0 and 23.5 degree N latitude?

Comment: Try: `gl.ylocator = mticker.FixedLocator([-23.5, 23.5])`

Comment: I did, it does not work. It still draws the latitude lines PLUS the 2 new ones i.e. -23.5 and 23.5

Comment: I see... try to remove all ticks http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.NullLocator, like: `gl.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(gl.NullLocator())`

Comment: I get this error `AttributeError: 'GeoAxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'gca'`

Comment: The function `gca()` returns the current axes, try simply without.

Comment: hmm, that does not seem to help either, I get this error message: `AttributeError: 'Gridliner' object has no attribute 'yaxis'`

Comment: I did this: `gl.yaxis.set_major_locator(gl.NullLocator())`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107472/discussion-between-user308827-and-maciej-a-czyzewski).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try gl.set_xlim(-23.5, 23.5), otherwise you are only changing where the tick marks appear rather than where your axes start and stop.